# Which technology should I use to draw on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-graphics

I'm developing an app which contains a view in which I have to draw several things.

My view looks like that:

[image: Screenshot app]

That's just a part of the entire view, but it's the same thing all the view's height.

This represents tracks for a train. So in my app, some trains will appear on the track.

My question is, which technology should I use:

- CoreGraphics to draw all on my view ?
- UITableView, then draw only a track by row and draw some components inside it (more easy to manage ?)
- Or other ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both: use a UITableView for the layout, then draw every UITableViewCell independently with CoreGraphics for example. That retains the flexibility of the table view, while unleashing the power of CoreGraphics for drawing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to use UITableView to draw my layout then, draw all stuff with CoreGraphics. Thanks again !

Comment: Always question whether you can use a UITableView when designing screens like this one. Its reuse mechanism is very efficient and it can save you lots of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and possibly the most efficient is to use a png and a `UIImageView`. You can perform simple looping animations with this and animate its position using the `.frame.origin` or `.center`.

If you want to have more control over the separate components, maybe you want parts of the train to animate differently due to various parameters, then you can use `CALayer`s to construct more elaborate animations.

As a last resort you can override `drawRect:` in a `UIView` subclass. In this method you can then use the `UIKit` wrappers for CoreGraphics functions (`UIBezierPath` etc). `UIKit` and CoreGraphics use different co-ordinate systems, using the UIKit wrappers mitigates this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response ! But I can do that only to animate my trains.
Is it a good idea to use a TableView to draw the layout ?